# Delete an Object from a JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this

```
var items = [{id:'1',token:'jj'},{id:'2',token:'kk'}];
```

I would like to delete an object from the array that matches `id = 2`

Here is my solution

```
//find the corresponding object
let obj=items.find((item) => item.id=='2');
//loop through the original and delete
```

Is there any other way to do this more efficiently??

Answer (score 0):

Use [**Array#filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function for deleting item/s from the array. It actually returns a new array containing those items which corresponds to the predicate.

```js
let items = [{id:'1',token:'jj'},{id:'2',token:'kk'}];
let filtered = items.filter(item => item.id !== '2');

console.log(filtered);
```

For removing from the original array

```js
let items = [{id:'1',token:'jj'},{id:'2',token:'kk'}];
let index = items.findIndex(item => item.id === '2');

items.splice(index, 1);

console.log(items);
```

Comment: But i need to modifiy the original array

Comment: It is not efficient. You need to get the index of that element from the array and use `splice` function. I have updated

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest using `splice`, this doesn't change the reference of the existing array but just removes the desired element..

```js
let items = [{id:'1',token:'jj'},{id:'2',token:'kk'}];

let indexToRemove = items.findIndex((eachElem) => {return eachElem.id == 2})
items.splice(indexToRemove, 1)
console.log(items)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the console :D

```js
var items = [{id:'1',token:'jj'},{id:'2',token:'kk'}, {id:'4',token:'kk'}, {id:'2',token:'kl'}];
items.forEach(item =>{
 if(item['id'] == '2') items.splice(items.indexOf(item),1)
})

console.log(items)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `splice()` with `forEach()` too:

```js
var items = [{id:'1',token:'jj'},{id:'2',token:'kk'}];
items.forEach((item, index) => {
   if(item.id === '2'){
     items.splice(index,1);
   }
});
console.log(items);
```